# Higher voted answers not rising to the top

Tags: support

I don't know if it's my browser, when reviewing the Tour, it said the best answers rise to the top. The accepted answer is always at the top, but other answers aren't.

From the Tour:

```
Good answers are voted up and rise to the top.

The best answers show up first so that they are always easy to find.
```

For example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-numeric-type-in-java/29331473#29331473) I see votes that have more votes than others being farther down.

Is this a problem with my browser *(I have noscript fully disabled)*, or is this intentional and only for the accepted answer?

Comment: Before the first question you see three tabs: active / oldest / votes, being the last one the default. In that case, the 1st answer will be the accepted and from next one on, it will be sorted by score. It is a bit unclear what you are asking but, could it be that you are sorting by another thing (active or oldest)?

Comment: As an aside, having read it all, your answer actually adds something valuable to that question, even though it's a good 5 years late.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this happen to me a while back and was confused at first, because the answers were no longer ordered by vote count, as I was used to.

You need to make sure that you have sorting by votes selected. It is selected by default, when you first join StackOverflow, but you may have accidentally changed the sorting with a misclick. You can find it here:

[image: Example]

Comment: Awesome. It's solved, thanks. I'm guessing I clicked it without thinking it would propagate on every page. I wonder if it's worth requesting a pop-up that says "will apply to all pages"...

Comment: @Water: That would *really quickly* get extremely annoying. Just as always having to click it again. Sometimes, one has to choose the least irritant...

Comment: @Deduplicator I should have included 'only once' in my comment, I agree that every time would be major overkill.